# why does my program not print the nextLine?

Tags: java

I have two classes. I want to print arrays of objects. These objects have attributes (some of them are `String`s), but when the program reads it as (nextLine), it will not print it.

Here is what I mean:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
String auther,Title,genre;
int ISBN,publicationYear,ISBN2;


if (Book.getBookNo()< archive_size){
    System.out.println("ISBN: ");
    ISBN=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Auther: ");
    auther=scan.nextLine(); //here is the problem if I choose next it's ok but no nextLine
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Published Year");
    publicationYear=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Title: ");
    Title=scan.nextLine();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Genre: ");
    genre=scan.next();
    libraryBooks[Book.getBookNo()] = new Book(ISBN,auther,publicationYear,Title,genre);

}

public static void printAll(){
    int i=0;
    for ( i=0 ; i<Book.getBookNo(); i++)
        System.out.println("Book "+(i+1)+"\nISBN: "+libraryBooks[i].getISBN()+
        "\nAuthor:           "+libraryBooks[i].getAuther()+
        "\npublishedyear: "+libraryBooks[i].getPublication()+"\nTitle: "+libraryBooks[i].getTitle()+
        "\nGenre: "+libraryBooks[i].getGenre()+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `sc.nextLine();` before `auther=scan.nextLine();`. It may need a flush.

Answer (score 0):

scan.nextInt() command only reads the int value , and to get the end line you have to add scan.nextLine() also like below

```
System.out.println("ISBN: ");
ISBN=scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine(); // It will solve the problem in question
System.out.println("Auther: ");
auther=scan.nextLine(); //here is the problem if I choose next it's ok but no nextLine
scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Published Year");
publicationYear=scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: This is interesting I faced it when started coding in java. It reminds me old days :)